# RegisterPropertyChangedCallback works only the first time

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This is a follow up question related to a control that needs to intercept when common control properties changes ([Inherit UserControl and hooking up to basic property events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824741/inherit-usercontrol-and-hooking-up-to-basic-property-events)).
When any base property changes (foregound, font style, size...), I need to invalidate the canvas and redraw the content.

I've ended up with calling this method inside the UserControl constructor:

```cs
RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyProperty dp, DependencyPropertyChangedCallback callback);
```

For example:

```cs
RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(ForegroundProperty, OnPropertyChanged);
RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(FontFamilyProperty, OnPropertyChanged);
RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(FontSizeProperty, OnPropertyChanged);
```

Inside `OnPropertyChanged` I proceed to rewire some property and invalidate the canvas in order to update the picture.

The control is inside a DataTemplate referenced by a Pivot (PivotHeaderTemplate). The default Foreground is the unselected status (semi-transparent `SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush`) and should get the default "white" when selected (SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush).

The control `Foreground` property is applied by a template, and according to the live tree it's updating, but OnPropertyChanges is called only the first time.
For example, the Pivot has 2 views: the first one starts selected and is white, and the second is unselected and is "grayish".
If I change the selection, the view changes, the Foreground property changes accordingly on both controls but `OnPropertyChanges` is not called, and my canvas doesn't change (because the invalidation logic is inside that method).

[UPDATE: as a workaround, I used the event LayoutUpdated to check what changed.]

For a test project, create a new UWP XAML project a new MyCanvas UserControl.

MyCanvas.xaml:

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="InheritControlProperty.Controls.MyCanvas"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:InheritControlProperty.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas x:Name="content" Width="50" Height="50"/>
</UserControl>
```

MyCanvas.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace InheritControlProperty.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class MyCanvas : UserControl
    {
        private Color Value
        {
            get { return (Foreground as SolidColorBrush)?.Color ?? Colors.Black; }
        }

        public MyCanvas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(ForegroundProperty, OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
        {
            content.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Value);
            //Logic for more complex canvas management here
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page x:Class="InheritControlProperty.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:InheritControlProperty"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:cntr="using:InheritControlProperty.Controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
        <Grid BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2">
            <cntr:MyCanvas Width="100" Height="50"/>
<!-- Try using Foreground="Red" -->
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Pivot Margin="20" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}">
    <PivotItem>Item 1</PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>Item 2</PivotItem>
</Pivot>
</Page>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are changing these properties on your `UserControl`?

Comment: I am not programmatically changing them, they are applied by a template. From the live property explorer window I see they are changed.

Comment: OK, I've added a Tapped event to forcibly change the foreground on tap, and in that case works. It seems the issue is only when it's applied by a template. I've changed the description on the OP to match the situation.

Comment: Please show the code on how the Foreground code is updated via a template.

Comment: It's the standard PivotHeaderItem template, I made no changes.

Comment: you should always show the code where the issue occurs, no matter how simple or standard it seems to be.

Comment: It doesn't "seem" standard, I haven't changed the standard template. I've added test code to show. If you check it with Live Tree, you can see MyCanvas has a Foreground brush different from what it shows. The only difference I cannot explain is that in my project it gets called at least once, but in this it never happens.